# computer not booting up consistently

Tags: boot, ssd

I'm running into some issues with booting up a single board computer that operates under some weird conditions and I'm not sure how to find the source of the issue. the errors I get when booting it  look something like these:
[error1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CzdXG7zbVroC45pSK9iallwLBCbke8ca/view?usp=sharing),
[error2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4TRfnMetTaTb65u7OdMV0-HG-E2A8yG/view?usp=sharing)
along sometimes booting up straight to the bios.

Now I'd guess this is simply a faulty SSD but the computer runs in some unusual conditions which may be causing the failure to boot, namely that the computer runs in cold conditions (down to around 0°C to 5°C) on top of this the electricity is not very stable in the field which means that regularly the computer gets its power cut abruptly, so I'm worried if these conditions would cause any ssd to fail eventually so that replacing the current one is pointless.

I tried putting the whole setup in the freezer for a bit, it run most of the time but the failure rate seems to increase a bit when it is colder, however it is really hard to tell due random nature of the problem. I also tried cutting the power of it and the problem seems more common when I unplug the computer from the power supply than when I unplug the power supply from the wall but again it seems very random and could just be my own confirmation bias. Any ideas on what is wrong and what I should try/check?

the ssd is a samsung 860 EVO and the computer is an axiomtek pico52r.

Comment: Get the Samsung Magician app (I use this) and get your SSD for errors .

Comment: smells like some hardware problem....